# Creating and logging into a Parse account using a SteamId

Tags: parse-platform, unity-game-engine

I’m just starting to get my feet wet working with Parse, so this question may be a little naïve.   I'm a bit at sea with the Parse documentation that tends to take a breezy approach, and I'm hoping for something a bit more concrete.

The scenario is that I’m creating a **desktop** app in *Unity* that is bound to a *Steam* account, and I am using *Parse* as a backend. I want to create a ParseUser associated with a SteamId, and connect to it each time I start my app; this should be transparent to the user.

I understand the general algorithm as:

```
Client requests an AuthSessionTicket via SteamAPI  
Client submits the ticket to Parse
Parse authenticates the ticket with Steam via WebAPI
Parse returns an authenticated ParseUser object to Client
```

I would expect that this is a standard problem with a standard solution. I’ve not found any resource that either has source, nor even advice. Can anyone point me in the right direction?